# C# Mysql await asynchronous

Tags: mysql, asynchronous

Is there any way to make the classic:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
CloseConnection();
```

use the async method to not freeze the whole app while making many operations?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using C#? If you use Entity Framework for your DAL, you can create a database context and query against it asynchronously. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx